# VS 2012 occasionally not finding the reference to another project in the solution

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2012, dll

I re-factored some functionality from an ASP.Net Project into a library project. Everything seemed to work fine but on my co-workers computer Visual Studio does not always find the assembly reference after a rebuild.

She writes some lines of code and sometimes the error list gets filled missing references. After a rebuild it is fine again and she can continue. It only occurs on her PC, I could not replicate it anywhere else.

I have already checked the Build Order and the Target Framework (Every Project uses .Net 4.5)

Comment: Have you double checked that the project is referencing the other project instead of the dll in the bin folder?

Comment: @TrevorPilley yes, the project is referenced.

Comment: I don't know what the problem was, but redoing everything by hand on my coworker's pc fixed it.